# ZAP Spider can't find form request on DVWA

Tags: zap

I'm tring using OWASP ZAP and DVWA. I want to find all request using spider. I was setting below:

- login admin user
- include default context
- Flag as Context: Formed-based Auth Login Request
- add admin user
- Forced user mode enable
- Flag as Context: Authentication Logged-in indicator

try to spider:
https://github.com/makaaso/stackoverflow/blob/main/zap-dvwa1.png

result below:
https://github.com/makaaso/stackoverflow/blob/main/zap-dvwa2.png

I expect below(this is manual scan result):
https://github.com/makaaso/stackoverflow/blob/main/zap-dvwa3.png

Is it possible to find request with parameter using spider?

Comment: This is already being dealt with on the User Group: https://groups.google.com/g/zaproxy-users/c/DijjoD5Q8cM

Comment: Thank you for your information. Spider was succeed.

Answer (score 0):

I did below and the spider was able to find the csrf URLs with parameters, I am using ZAP 2.10.0 and DVWA master zip package.

- start a new session
- double click Contexts / Default Context
- Include in Context: https://127.0.0.1/dvwa/.*
- Authentication - Formed-based Auth Login Request

  - Login Form Targe URL:  https://127.0.0.1/dvwa/login.php
  - URL to get login form:  https://127.0.0.1/dvwa/login.php
  - Login request post data: `username={%username%}&password={%password%}&user_token={%user_token%}&Login=Login`
  - Regx pattern for Logged In message: `\QLocation: index.php\E`
- add user: `admin` / `password`
- Excluded from Spider: `\Qhttps://127.0.0.1/dvwa/logout.php\E`
- enable Forced user mode
- Tools / Options / Anti-CSRF Tokens - add `user_token`
- right click Contexts / Default Context > Spider
  Starting point: https://127.0.0.1/dvwa/, select `admin` user
- start scan

Spider Messages show

```
...
https://127.0.0.1/dvwa/vulnerabilities/csrf/
https://127.0.0.1/dvwa/vulnerabilities/csrf/?Change=Change&password_conf=ZAP&password_current=ZAP&password_new=ZAP&user_token=5bbc6fdff77b435b3f754518d236a368
https://127.0.0.1/dvwa/vulnerabilities/csrf/index.php
https://127.0.0.1/dvwa/vulnerabilities/csrf/index.php?Change=Change&password_conf=ZAP&password_current=ZAP&password_new=ZAP&user_token=3a8691e372ddd7b6f2c30f2a3feae1be
...
```

Comment: The ZAP team has a FAQ for DVWA: https://www.zaproxy.org/faq/details/setting-up-zap-to-test-dvwa/

Comment: @daba72 Thank you for your information. Spider was succeed.